# Why am I am getting the error ":main() must have int return type"?

Tags: c++

I created a c++ code for binary to Decimal conversion

```
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int binaryToDecimal(long int n){
int decimal=0,i=0;
while(n>0){
decimal+=(n%10)*pow(2,i);
n/=10;
i++;
}
return decimal;
}
void main(){
    long int num;
    cout<<"Enter a binary number:";
    cin>>num;
    int d= binaryToDecimal(num);
    cout<<"\nDecimal number:"<<d;
}
```

However I am getting the error `:main() must have int return type`
Why should I have my main as int return type when it does'nt need to return anything?
What's wrong with having a void return type?

Comment: Because `main` must have `int` return type.

Comment: `main` returns the exit code.

Comment: becaue `main` must indeed have `int` return type. Most of the time the compiler is right

Comment: Simply because the C++ standard requires main to return an `int` (to support operating systems with the concept of process return codes).  See here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function

Comment: Also the use of `pow` is inadvisable as there are no guarantees regarding its precision. Far better to maintain a "running" power, using say `p *= 2` at each step.

Comment: OT:  you can replace `pow(2, i)` with `1 << i;`, which usually involves one or two instructions instead of a function call.